# how to send the output of a command that runs on the connected machine, to a file in the connecting machine

Tags: bash, ssh

I am making a script to access a bunch of machines through ssh and run the `df -h` command to check if their disk usage is getting near 100% , my problem is that I can't run the command on the machine that when I run the command, i cant send it to a file in the machine that I am using to connect.
I have tried this

```
df -h > /dir/file
```

but that just creates a file in the machine I am connected to.
How would I go about doing what I am trying to do?

the full code that im using to do this is

```
expect <<-EOF
spawn ssh -oPort=23 x.x.x.x df -h > /home/file
expect "*password: " {send "password\r"}
expect "*#" {send "exit\r"}
EOF
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the redirection to the beginning of the heredoc:

```
expect <<-EOF > /home/file
spawn ssh -oPort=23 x.x.x.x df -h
expect "*password: " {send "root\r"}
expect "*#" {send "exit\r"}
EOF
```

(untested)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
ssh remoteMachine 'df -h' > path/to/local/file
```

Comment: it just creates a file in the remote machine, i dont know if its because its inside an heredoc and a expect spawn i will update my explanation to show more code

Comment: I think the file on the remote machine is left over from your earlier efforts. Try running `uname -a` instead of `df -h` and check both files.

Comment: I have confirmed that its not a leftover, every time i run the script the file in my local machine is blank and a file with the same name is created in the machine i am connecting to

Comment: Which script? I didn't suggest a script, it's one single, simple command.

Comment: Oh, I see. You have edited your question and are running under `expect` for some reason. You really should set up password-less ssh access instead of saving passwords in scripts.

Comment: yeah i know, i cant do that right now because i dont have permission or acess to do something like that in the servers im connecting too, by the way sorry i didnt post that part of the code sooner, thanks for you help tough